# OpenStreetMap tile server for dark theme

Tags: openstreetmap, docker

I just created a docker image for a dark (black) theme using OpenStreetMap data, and after running docker commands, the data is not loading. These are the docker commands I have

1. sudo docker volume create osm-dark
2. sudo time docker run -v /home/osm_data/india-latest.osm.pbf:/data/region.osm.pbf -v osm-dark:/var/lib/postgresql/15/main cvpr/openstreetmap-tile-server import
3. sudo docker volume create osm-dark-rendered-tiles
4. sudo docker run -p 3033:80 -p 6044:5432 -e THREADS=10 -e “OSM2PGSQL_EXTRA_ARGS=-C 4096” -v osm-dark:/var/lib/postgresql/15/main -e ALLOW_CORS=enabled -v osm-dark-rendered-tiles:/var/lib/mod_tile -d cvpr/openstreetmap-tile-server run

Comment: Where does "cvpr/openstreetmap-tile-server" come from?  I'm guessing it might be based on "overv/openstreetmap-tile-server" which https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/ uses; if so, that documentation might explain what is happening.  If you can spin up a VM somewhere and try without Docker, it'd be easier.  Also try a smaller .pbf file than India as a test first.